# Have error trying to modify a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add a column to my table and make it a foreign key but I keep getting this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY(idplayer) REFERENCES
>   players(playersid)' at line 1

below is my code before the alter statement:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions 
  ( 
     transid  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
     type     VARCHAR(20), 
     fromteam VARCHAR(30), 
     toteam   VARCHAR(30), 
     idplayer INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY(transid) 
  );
```

Now I try to alter the idplayer and make it a foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE transactions
MODIFY idplayer INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
FOREIGN KEY(idplayer) REFERENCES players(playersid)
```

Please an assistance would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you are missing a comma after `NOT NULL`, Second you need to tell mysql to add the `CONSTRAINT`. Give this a try:

```
ALTER TABLE `events`
MODIFY idplayer INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_Name` FOREIGN KEY (idplayer) REFERENCES players(playersid);
```

Comment: @Ryab Naddy why add a constraint FK_NAME

Comment: I guess it is optional, I have just always used it, but the main thing is, that you missed the comma